# How to use -source in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compatibility, diamond-operator

How can I fix this? When I trying to compile some code, I get this message:

```
java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

On my PC I have this settings and I using IDEA:

```
C:\Windows\System32>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_25

C:\Windows\System32>java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

What exactly should I do to compile it? Where should I place '-source 7'?

Comment: What is your project language level set at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project structure menu (`ctrl+alt+shift+s`) and change your "Project Language Level" to "7.0 Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch, etc.". It's under the Project tab in your sidebar to the left.

Comment: Done.It's compiled now :) Thanks.

Comment: See the request about making it more discoverable: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121971